# Laravel комманда не найдена

Tags: laravel

Установил Apache, mysql, php7, так же скачал composer, в папке которую сделал "доменом" сделал composer init.
Теперь хочу установить Laravel:
Делаю

> Сначала загрузите установщик Laravel с помощью Composer.

composer global require "laravel/installer"

Сделал, потом:

> laravel new blog

Но пишет Laravel команда не найдена, а выше написано

> Указав в качестве PATH директорию ~/.composer/vendor/bin, станет возможным использование команды laravel.

Как указать PATH в убунту 16 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы узнать, где лежит `bin`, выполните команду:

```
composer global config bin-dir --absolute
```

Установка переменных окружения в Ubuntu: [правильный путь](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)
Простой путь. Добавить в `./.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/path/to/composer/bin:$PATH"
```

Для обновления без перезапуска:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH="/path/to/dir:$PATH"
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?